# Make Version Code & Version Name using Codename1

Tags: codenameone

Good day... 
When make changes to APK when the application is alreay in Play store Or App store, how to make the Version Code & Version name in codenameone like "menifest file" as well so that existing users will receive our update.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project and there is general properties under codenameone tab as shown below image and update version(eg: 1.1) and this will code version and the play store and app store will show update button
[image]